# How to convert the data an interface{} holds into a slice (when the structure of interface{}'s data is known)?

Tags: go

I receive data from a function `apiFunc()` which returns an `interface{}`.

I know that in this specific case, the data that is returned is a slice of `struct` such as

```
type Data struct {
    hello string
    world int
}
```

I do not know how large the slice is (the API could have sent a JSON array of one or 100 of such entities).

**How should I declare the variable `myData` so that it is a slice of `Data`, made from the returned values of `apiFunc()`?**

I know that

```
ret := apiFunc()
myData := ret.([]Data)
```

does not work (it panics with `interface conversion: interface {} is []interface {}, not []main.Data`)

Comment: @StevenPenny: oh yes, this is a great question! (mine :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Data struct {
    hello string
    world int
}

func apiFunc() interface{} {
    return []Data{{hello: "first hello", world: 1}, {hello: "second hello", world: 2}}
}

func main() {
    ret := apiFunc()
    fmt.Println(ret.([]Data))
}
```

Go playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/SOGr6Fj-wO5

Make sure your `apiFunc()` actually returns a `Data` slice and not an `interface` slice

If it is an interface slice you need to do the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Data struct {
    hello string
    world int
}

func apiFunc() interface{} {
    toReturn := make([]interface{}, 2)
    toReturn[0] = Data{hello: "first hello", world: 1}
    toReturn[1] = Data{hello: "second hello", world: 2}
    return toReturn
}

func main() {
    ret := apiFunc()
    interfaceSlice := ret.([]interface{})
    dataSlice := make([]Data, len(interfaceSlice))
    for index, iface := range interfaceSlice {
        dataSlice[index] = iface.(Data)
    }
    fmt.Println(dataSlice)
}
```

Go playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/TsfMuKj7nZc

Comment: `apiFunc()` is not mine. I do not know the intervals, I just know that it returns `interface{}` and that what was received in `apiFunc()` was a JSON array of elements equivalent to `Data`.

Comment: I added code in case `apiFunc()` does return an interface slice. Try both, and if neither work `apiFunc()` doesn't return a data slice.

Comment: @WoJ note that `x.(T)` is a *type assertion*, it is not a conversion, nor a type cast, nor type coercion (the latter two don't even exist in Go). You are **asserting** that the dynamic type of `x` is [identical](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity) to the type `T`. That means that unless you provide a type that satisfies the identicality rules, enumerated in the above link, the type assertion *will* fail. So you first need to type assert the returned value to the actual type and then convert that, probably manually, to the target type.

Comment: ... You cannot type assert it to the type you **wish** it to be, nor to the type that's "equivalent" to the actual type, equivalent is not equal, it's probably not identical and is therefore not good enough!

Comment: @mkopriva: thank you very much. Your comment made things much more clear (I am still struggling with the idea of interface, but now I understand that I had it all wrong). I will read again all the docs/blogs I read about interfaces with your comment in mind. Thanks.

Comment: @mkopriva Do you suggest an edit to my answer? If so which?

Comment: @Cookie04 there's not enough information in the question to provide an accurate answer. The `apiFunc`, presumably an imported func that WoJ has no control over, probably returns `[]interface{}` where each element is of type `map[string]interface{}`. This is the default type when unmarshaling json, which we know the `apiFunc` does, into an `*interface{}`. If that is the case then the correct answer would be to first type assert the result to `[]interface{}`, then loop over that, then type assert each individual element inside the loop to `map[string]interface{}`, ...

Comment: ... then from that map manually initialize the concrete struct type, and of course each element inside the map will have to be type asserted if the target struct type's fields are of concrete types and not empty interfaces, then shove the initialized struct value into the slice of concrete types and you're done. Again, however, the question, since it is based on some fundamental misconceptions about interfaces, is not specific enough for us to know for sure whether the above is or is not the solution.

Comment: @Cookie04 in short, no, I do not have a suggestion for an edit ;).

Comment: @WoJ I'm glad you found the comments helpful. FWIW, I had trouble wrapping *my* head around interfaces at the beginning too. Once understood however, they will become very simple and obvious, and a joy!